# C++11 no matching function for call to ‘std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, std

I have a struct `msg`:

```
struct msg {
    //destination port
    int addr;
    //data
    unsigned long long payload;

    //prioritized flag
    bool isPrio;

    //construcor?
    msg(int a, int p, bool b) : addr(a), payload(p),isPrio(b) { }

    msg() : addr(0), payload(0), isPrio(false) { }

    ...
};
```

And a class `distributor` which receives `msg`s via SystemC `sc_in` and pushes some elements to a 2 dimensional vector `std::vector<std::vector <msg>> buffer`:

```
class distributor: public sc_module {
    public:
        sc_vector<sc_in<msg>> inputMsg;
        std::vector<std::vector <msg>> buffer;
        int n, m, bufferSize;
        ...


        distributor(sc_module_name name, int n, int m, int bufferSize) : //n -> number of inputs, m -> number of outputs
            sc_module(name),
            inputMsg("inputMsg", n),
            n(n),
            m(m),
            buffer(m),
            bufferSize(bufferSize)
            ...
        {
            SC_HAS_PROCESS(distributor);
            SC_METHOD(receive); sensitive << ...;
            ...
        }

        void receive() {
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                msg newMessage = inputMsg.at(i).read();
                if(buffer.at(newMessage.addr).size() >= bufferSize) continue;
                if(newMessage.isPrio) buffer.at(newMessage.addr).insert(0, newMessage); //<- ERROR OCCURS HERE
                else buffer.at(newMessage.addr).push_back(newMessage);
            }
        }

        ...
};
```

In the commented line the following error occurs:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<msg>::insert(int, msg&)’
     if(newMessage.isPrio) buffer.at(newMessage.addr).insert(0, newMessage);
                                                                          ^
```

Why does the error occur ?

`buffer.at(newMessage.addr)` is `std::vector <msg>` so it should take an object of type `msg` which is `newMessage`...

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) takes an *iterator* as the first argument, not an *index.* You probably want this:

```
void add_to_front(std::vector<msg> &vector, const msg &message)
{
  vector.insert(begin(vector), message);
}


if(newMessage.isPrio) add_to_front(buffer.at(newMessage.addr), newMessage);
```

I've wrapped the call in a function because it references the vector twice, and it will make the code read better anyway.